# Handle html form checkbox using spring tools?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have the following form:

```
<form action="findBySkills"><br>
    <c:forEach items="${skills}" var="skill">
        ${skill.name} <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="${skill.id}"> <br>
    </c:forEach>
```

How can I read checked `${skill.id}` from my `@Сontroller`?

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: I Want get checked ${skill.id} in my @Controller java class!

Comment: See docs at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-checkboxestag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ModelAttribute`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html) to pass multiple items from the checkbox

```
@RequestMapping("/findBySkills")  
public ModelAndView processSkill(@ModelAttribute SkillDTO skillDTO)) {  
    String[] skills = skillDTO.getSkills();
    ...
}
```

where `SkillDTO` is a simple POJO

```
public class SkillDTO {

    private String[] skills;

    public String[] getSkills() {
        return skills;
    }

    public void setSkills(String[] skills) {
        this.skills = skills;
    }
}
```

Note: None of this has been tested

Comment: there are nany skill id might be selected

Comment: That's just a preference, I always use the Spring tags

Answer (score 0):

you will get by way shown below,

```
String[] parameterValues = request.getParameterValues("skills");
```

parameterValues will contain all checked checkboxes.

for more info:
http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/GetParameterValuesMethod.shtml

This link explain all the html form elements accessing way at Servlet end using Spring. 
Annotation based: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-annotation-example/

Comment: @user2674303 people are here to show you direction and guidance, not to  write the code as per your business logic. If you read mentioned link you will be able to map in your need.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple and it is not necessary to create DTO. 
Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String form(@RequestParam(required = false) List<Integer> checks) {
    if(checks != null) { // if checkbox is not selected it is null
        for(Integer check: checks) {
            System.out.println(check);
        }
    }
    return "index-client";
}
```

jsp:

```
<form action="${home}/test" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="checks" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="checks" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="checks" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Works for spring 3.1.1.RELEASE (don't know about older versions)